# how to avoid image getting loaded from the cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am using asp.net file upload control

I am uploading the image to the server as as `UserID+"ProfilePic"` .
After uploading I am setting an image src to this via code behind

```
string FolderPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PATH"].ToString();
string assoid = HttpContext.Current.Session["strAssociateId"].ToString()+"ProfilePic.jpg";
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    try
    {
        string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(FolderPath +assoid);
        string imagePath = "serverpath" +assoid;
        face_crop_original.Src = imagePath;  //Problem is here
    }
}
```

So here what happens is the image is getting uploaded, but when I set the `image.Src=xxxx` it's taking the old image from cache!! Please help.

Comment: Use 
**FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(FolderPath +assoid+datetime.now);**
it will requrest for new image to your server

Comment: ya but it will upload new image everytime to server!!
I thought of replacing old with new one :( 

Is there anyway we can instruct browser not to use cache?!

Comment: You are replacing new one with new name you can delete order one @vignesh and adding newer one will save new image to folder and then you will have new image at front end

Comment: Thanks @dholakiyaankit :) I browsed and found one more simpler way !! :)

Comment: I have posted an answer please check it out ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution which is working for me :)

You can check the source [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-remove-delete-image-from-browser-cache-when-Image-is-changed-in-ASPNet.aspx)

What I did is I attached the `datetime.now` as @dholakiyaankit suggested but in a different place

```
 string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(FolderPath +assoid);
                    string imagePath = "server path" +assoid;
                    face_crop_original.Src = imagePath+"?"+DateTime.Now;
```

NOTE: Here my imagepath variable will be "xxxxxx.jpg" so

```
 face_crop_original.Src = imagePath+"?"+DateTime.Now;
```

will be `"http://xxxxxxxx.com/imagename.jpg?Randomnumber"`

This enabled me to upload the image with same name (USERID+"Profilepic") and i need not write code for deleting older file as the name will be same and it will be replaced in server !

Comment: Same logic  have posted in my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string VersionCssUrl(string url)
    {
        // Get physical path.
        try
        {
            var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(url);
            return url + "?v=" + String.Format(File.GetLastWriteTime(path).ToString("MMddyyhhmmss"));
        }
        catch
        {
            return url;
        }
    }
```

and your code will look like this

```
<img src="<%= VersionCssUrl("your src".ToString()) %>" />
```

Now,**Explaination** you know what will happen is this will request the file everytime but it will **check modification date** of your file so you will have previous one if does not changed will definately **load from cache**.....

and if your **file has been changed** it will **load new file automatically** this all depends on your datetime.....

i hope this will help you regards...:)